# MPAndroidChart Target Square in LineChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to be able to draw a sort of 'target' square for a game I am making in MPAndroidChart. Currently, I have real-time sensor data that is being plotted on the chart. I would like to be able to draw some sort of 'target' square so a person's goal is to get the line chart to plot inside the square. I've illustrated what I mean below:

[image]

Is there some way to draw a square within the background or just on the line chart? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be done by sub-classing the chart class (e.g. LineChart) and then overriding the onDraw() method. In the overridden onDraw() you can draw the square you need directly onto the canvas and then call super.onDraw() to complete the rendering of the chart.

Comment: Ok thanks @PaulT, I'll try that out